# How can I manage the navigation with present modally and show?

Tags: ios

I have there view controller A B C
In A , there is a navigation right button, when the right button clicked, A present B by present modally design. B is a tableview controller, when cell did selected B show C . Now If C click the back button , C will go to B, but not go to A.
How can I let C go to A ,when I click the back button.
I know every view controller has its own navigation controllers, and how different navigation controllers communicate?Seeking for help.

Comment: how you are moving from B->C using Push Navigationcontroller  or using Present animation?

Comment: I just only use performSeguewithIdentifier

Comment: is it a push segue or present segue..?

Comment: A to B is present modally      B to C is show segue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution is if you use A-B using push segue then from C view controller you can go back to A Viewcontroller using

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or other way would be to present the A viewcontroller modally

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewController_A *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"]; //replace the identifier
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an action for back button in view controller for c.

and write the following code in it. [Objective C]

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerA *controller = (ViewControllerA *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks..I think it will work. But this A is a new instance. Any way for going back to the same A?